# How can I indicate the type of the context of a bound member function called from an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I have the following (contrived) TypeScript code:

```js
interface hasSpecialField {
  specialField: string;
}

interface hasStringFn {
  fn: (this: hasSpecialField) => string;
}

function whatIsMyContext(this: hasSpecialField): string {
  return this.specialField;
}

function getObj(): hasStringFn {
  let toBeBound: hasSpecialField = {
    specialField: 'Can whatIsMyContext() access me?'
  };

  let obj: hasStringFn = {
    fn: whatIsMyContext.bind(toBeBound)
  };

  return obj;
}

let parentObj = getObj();
let result = parentObj.fn();

console.log(result);
```

If I write out and execute the JavaScript equivalent of this code, without any type annotations, I see the following:

```
Can whatIsMyContext() access me?
undefined
```

Which makes sense, because `whatIsMyContext` is explicitly bound to `toBeBound`, which has the field referenced by `this.specialField`. Also, the last line is the `console.log`, which does not return a value, hence `undefined`.

However, TypeScript throws an error for this code:

> The 'this' context of type 'hasStringFn' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'hasSpecialField'. Property 'specialField' is missing in type 'hasStringFn'.

The error message points to the line `let result = parentObj.fn();`. It seems that TypeScript thinks that `whatIsMyContext` (aliased by `fn`) has the wrong `this` context when called from `parentObj`. Why does it think this? How should I write my code to preserve type information while also signalling to TypeScript that my context bindings are correct?

Comment: @deceze According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html, TypeScript lets you use `this` as the first argument to a method in order to indicate the type of the scope.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *lexical scope*, which is about the variables in scope. It's called the "`this` context" or "receiver".

Comment: @Bergi Huh...I've never distinguished between them in JS. You learn something new every day, I guess. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as typechecking is concerned, interface `hasStringFn` as you declared it is unusable on its own. Your declaration says that `fn` can only be called on an object that has `specialField`:

```
let a: hasStringFn;
let b: hasSpecialField;
a.fn();        // error
a.fn.call(b)   // ok
```

One possible way out of this is to declare an interface with function property `fn` that does not even have `this` parameter, much like standalone functions do:

```
interface hasBoundStringFn {
    fn: () => string;
}
```

Then this code compiles:

```
function getObj(): hasBoundStringFn {
  let toBeBound: hasSpecialField = {
    specialField: 'Can whatIsMyContext() access me?'
  };

  let obj: hasStringFn = {
    fn: whatIsMyContext.bind(toBeBound)
  };

  return obj;
}

let parentObj = getObj();
let result = parentObj.fn();
```

next question:

> So am I correct in concluding that TypeScript is looking at the
>   interface, not the implementation, when it throws that error? In other
>   words, the code is valid but TypeScript looks no further than the
>   interface in parsing it?

Yes, if you explicitly declare variable or function type, the compiler will believe you (as long as it does not contradict the usage in the code) and will look no further.

You can check what the compiler will get from the implementation by removing as much type annotations as possible:

```
interface hasSpecialField {
  specialField: string;
}

function whatIsMyContext(this: hasSpecialField): string {
  return this.specialField;
}

function getObj() {
  let toBeBound = {
    specialField: 'Can whatIsMyContext() access me?'
  };

  let obj = {
    fn: whatIsMyContext.bind(toBeBound)
  };

  return obj;
}

let parentObj = getObj();
let result = parentObj.fn();

console.log(result);
```

In your case, the code compiles, but it's not because TypeScript determinted that implementation is valid. It's because the inferred type for `getObj` is

```
function getObj(): { fn: any; }
```

You see, `bind` is built-in, compiler has no access to it's implementation, and it has to believe the type declaration for `bind` as it's given in TypeScript standard library.

And as things stand now, `bind`, `call` and `apply` are [effectively untyped](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212).

So in this particular case, you have to provide your own explicit types and interfaces to make compiler check your code.

Comment: "*does not care much*" would rather be `(this: Any) => string` or `() => string`, right?

Comment: Nope, `any` would be totally careless - `any` turns off type checking completely. Empty object type `{}` (object type without any properties) fits better because bound function does not use any properties of the object it's called upon, it uses bound object, type of which does not matter at all at the call site.

Comment: So am I correct in concluding that TypeScript is looking at the interface, not the implementation, when it throws that error? In other words, the code is valid but TypeScript looks no further than the interface in parsing it?

Comment: @artem Yes, that's what I mean, a bound function doesn't care at all about the receiver it is called upon, be it an object or something else.

Comment: @Bergi I agree that from the caller point of view `any` makes sense. I just have an aversion to `any` because it means 'untyped', so every time I see `any` I'm wary of unintended consequences. Also, from the implementation point of view, `any` means "does not care and does anything it wants with it", while empty object means "does not care and does not use it" (`void` would be even better, but typescript objects to `this` parameter typed as `void`). Anyway the solution to this dilemma is elusively simple - just don't declare `this` parameter at all. I updated answer again.